# where to add printk.time ?

Tags: linux, printk

This is a very simple question yet I have little knowledge in Linux and starting to build it .

I am trying to debug the kernel using printk times. I am following this website: http://elinux.org/Printk_Times and in the middle it says to use it: "When booting the kernel, add the option "printk.time=1" (or "time" for older kernels) on the kernel command line "

Where is kernel command line ? am I to add this line in the grub and update the grub ?

Please advise on where should I add this command,

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's for menu.lst.

```
title Desktop -- openSUSE 12.1
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-3.3.1 printk.time=1
    initrd /initrd-3.3.1
```

Comment: Can I do same thing for my kexec ? I execute kexec using this command :  kexec -l /boot/vmlinuz-`uname -r` --append="root=/dev/sda1 1 irqpoll reset_devices load_state"

Comment: Where can I add it in such case ? I tried after the /boot/vmlinuz-uname-r but it didn't work... Can you please advise ? thank you

Comment: Within the append value, obviously.